# Copying data between spread sheets - error of "incorrect range height line 21"

Tags: excel, vba

i have 2 spread sheets i have my master spread sheet and my source i want to copy the row A-G and paste it in the master sheet but it says i have the incorrect height range

> `"incorrect range height line 21"`

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get Spreadsheets
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nqHrgEEYdiHmgfyIhpoFvG7iroDXWLhGPp1w_NJHI8s");
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Gw3PH9f3CCKqjurLFQMDNSO_CBB3Q7m3JXbaQk-wZKc");

  // Set Sheets
var source_sheet = source.getSheetByName("Meeting");
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Team A");

// Get target last row
var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();

// Set Ranges
var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:G50");
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":G"+(last_row+1));

  // Fetch values
  var values = source_range.getValues();

  // Save to spreadsheet
  target_range.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: If @Thomas Inzina solution meets your requirement, then please accept his answer by ticking check mark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to copy 50 rows and paste it into a single row.

```
var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:G50");
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":G"+(last_row+1));
```

Try

```
var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:G50");
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":G"+(last_row+51));
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas it works.

but i have another problem, it is copying the data and pasting it from line 5 and below how do i get it to paste from line 2 and down?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the two sheets.  I would think that either your target sheet has data 5 rows down or your first 5 source rows are blank.